# How to Get Custom Week Desc in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerpivot, ssas-tabular

Basis on below data I want to add a calculated column with **Week Description**

I've done it in excel by typing it manually.

Also my week is starting from Thursday and ends on Wednesday hence I've Used this function to get the weekday `WEEKDAY('Calendar'[date],14)`

Requesting you to help me with a dax code which can be used to create a new calculated column with  week information as shown below in third column.

The logic would be : If the date is current week then the value will be "This Week" else if the
date is in last week then "This Week -1" else if the date is in last to last week then "This Week - 2" and so on.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The weekday can be calculated as following:

```
Weekday = WEEKDAY([Date] + 3)
```

We do a shift of 3 days to make Thursday the start of the week

Next, we get the WeekDesc in two steps, frist we calculate the difference between now and the date in weeks and as second step we use an if statement to create the correct sting (and logic).

```
WeerDesc = 
    var weeksPast = DATEDIFF(now(), [Date] + 3,WEEK) 
    return if ( weeksPast = 0, "This Week", "This Week" & weeksPast)
```

As you can see you can use variables in your DAX, I would recommend using them to keep the overview.

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

We can do this also in this way (as a measure if you need only label to display on rows):

```
DayOfWeek = WEEKDAY(SELECTEDVALUE('CAL'[Date]),14)
DiffToToday = DATEDIFF(SELECTEDVALUE('CAL'[Date]),TODAY(),DAY)
Label = CONCATENATE("This Week",  (DIVIDE( CAL[DiffToToday] + CAL[DayOfWeek],7) -1) *-1 )
```

[image]

Of course, we can do all steps in one measure.